# How to make two div with centered in two lines

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two block (DIV) and both are centered to the screen, and I want to keep those blocks vertical line by line as per the attachment, please note that parent div is in `display:flex`

[image]

```css
.wrapper{
width:100%;
float:left;
background:#ccc;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
}
.div1 {
margin: 10px auto;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid #000;
background: #fff;
}
.div2 {
margin: 10px auto;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid #000;
background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="div1"> Block 1 </div>
   <div class="div2"> Block 2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you really need the `display: flex` ? It's not required in this case. Just use `text-align: center`.

Comment: I have used flex to make the child div vertically align centered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using a `flexbox` change the *flex-axis* to vertical using `flex-direction: column`.

See snippet below:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.div1 {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
}
.div2 {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">Block 1</div>
  <div class="div2">Block 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, added the 'flex-direction:column' but lost the vertical align middle

Comment: for vertical-align now use `justify-content: space-around` or `space-between` as you see it fit...